# How to display multiple images in one post coming from json in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, view

Guys i am working on a project. I want to display multiple images in a post like facebook please give me any suggestion that what method i can adopt to make this, image's data come from json i don't have any issue with json i can handle it but the problem is multiple images in one post.

and how to design xml of above mentioned problem.
[image: the post show in image]

Comment: you can make this type of view using https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Comment: thank you for your answer i try this

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GridLayout: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

```
<GridLayout
bla bla....>

<!--First Image, spans three rows-->
<ImageView
bla bla......
android:layout_row="0"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_rowSpan="3"
/>

<!--Other Images, takes up one cell each-->
<ImageView
bla bla......
android:layout_row="0"
android:layout_column="1"/>

<ImageView
bla bla......
android:layout_row="0"
android:layout_column="2"/>

<ImageView
bla bla......
android:layout_row="0"
android:layout_column="3"/>

</GridLayout>
```